# Calling a batch from java requires to be started from the current batch file folder

Tags: java

I am starting a batch file from my java program which will stop some tomcats, the batch itself works if it will be started from the command line. But starting it from java it does not work, the problem is that the batch wont be called from the folder where its persited. So it cannot find some files, My question is how can i switch to the folder where the batch lies and then start the batch, so that it is runninng from its folder and will find the necessary files.

For example the batch lies in the folder c:\foobar\mybatch.cmd

Here is my code how currently the batch will be called from java

```
public void startBatch(Path batchPath) {

    if (batchPath == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cannot start batch without path to it");
    }
    if (!Files.exists(batchPath)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("batch does not exist " + batchPath.toString());
    }

    try {
        log.info("starting batch " + batchPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        String command = "cmd.exe /c " + batchPath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
        Process p;
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        p.waitFor();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            log.info(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Comment: any advice? Can I navigate somehow into the folder of my batch, so that java will call it from there?

Answer (score 0):

You should just put `cd c:\foobar\` in the batch file itself.